# laravel: unable to use model methods in controller to get attribute

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I've been trying to do this for a while now. Most of the time, I solve it by using accessors. I'm currently trying to get if the column exists and I created a function in my model which is suppose to return boolean.

Model code:

```
class Inventory extends Model
{
    protected $attributes = ['inventory'];   
    protected $appends = ['colorThumb'];

    public function hasAttribute($attr){
      return array_key_exists($attr, $this->attributes);
    }
}
```

Controller code:

```
public function allInvOperation(Request $request){
    $inv = Inventory::where('is_deleted', 0)->with(['product', 'size','color'])->orderByDesc('id')->get();       
    if(!is_null($request->searchText)){
        dd($inv->hasAttribute('inventory'));

        $inv = Inventory::where('is_deleted', 0)->with(['product', 'size','color'])->orderByDesc('id');

        if($request->inv_filter == 'inventory'){
            $inv = $inv->where('inventory', 'like', "%".$request->searchText."%")->get();
        }
        if($request->inv_filter == 'code'){
            $inv = $inv->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($request){
                $q->where('code', "%".$request->searchText."%");
            })->get();
        }
    }
```

**ERROR**

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::hasAttribute does not exist.
```

Comment: Please post the code as a code snippet in here rather than a image.

Comment: Please share the code you use to query the database. It seems you are using Model functions on a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are doing `hasAttribute` on is a `Collection` of objects, you need to use `first` on that query to get a single result on which you can later do `hasAttribute`